# Uncaught Error: Module phonegap-nfc.NFC does not exists. (IONIC NFC PLUGIN)

Tags: ionic-framework, plugins, syntax-error, nfc

I updated the phonegap-nfc plugin to the latest version 1.0.2 but it still doesn't work. Although the error kinda changed a wee bit.

With version 1.0.1, I get:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word
Uncaught Error: Module phonegap-nfc.NFC does not exists.
```

And with version 1.0.2, I get:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier plugins/phonegap-nfc/www/phonegap-nfc.js:517
Uncaught Error: Module phonegap-nfc.NFC does not exist.
```

image:

[image: NFC PLUGIN IONIC]

I'm using:

**cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)**

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

**global packages:**

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

**local packages:**

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9

Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0

Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

Any solution?

Comment: Seems like an open issue with the plugin https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc/issues/325

Comment: There's a bug with the new release and older versions of Ionic. Until that's fixed, try to use version 0.7.3 of phonegap-nfc.

Answer (score 0):

Some ES6 code was added to phonegap-nfc.js, which breaks older phones when the code isn't transpiled. This is fixed in [phonegap-nfc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phonegap-nfc) version 1.0.3 and works with older phones again.

Comment: Glad it helped! Please, consider accepting my answer.